# How do you filter out traffic in Universal Analytics from employees on cellphones accessing the company website?

Tags: google-analytics, mobile, universal-analytics

We have employees that access the company website using their smartphones.  The smartphones connect with different ip addresses depending on if they are on a wifi access point, the 3G and 4G networks of AT&T and Verizon.  We also have users who access the site from home.  There is a dropdown menu at the top of our site that reads "employees" and has links to employee related content.

So how do you filter this traffic from the website?

Answer (score 1):

Using cookies would be the most likely solution.  If the employees section is password-protected, then set it whenever anyone logs-in.  If not, you may have to make them visit the site via a hidden url that sets it.

The cookie will remain even if their ip changes.

If a cookie is set, you can then add additional information about the user to your Analytics code that you can filter from your analytics results.